# MyEclipse 8.5 creating 'maven-archetype-quickstart' has encountered a prob?

Tags: maven, myeclipse

I use the built-in maven of MyEclipse 8.5 to create maven projects.
It shows the following error:
Image is here:[pic](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/38/e824b899a9014c082f9ec03.jpg/)

Sorry, because I'm new I can't post pictures here yet.

I did it twice on two computers (both are MyEclipse 8.5), but the error was the same.
I use a Eclipse to do the same job and it is successful.

But when using MyEclipse 8.5 to do the job if check "create a simple project (skip archetype selection)" during the process, the project can be created and no error happens, but there is no the folder "Maven Dependencies" in the project created in Package Explorer.
Is this a bug of this version of MyEclipse? Because Eclipse Indigo works fine on this.

Comment: I've made a change. I think it should work now. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a simple project, the folder Maven Dependencies is missing simply because there are no Maven Dependencies in a simple project. Just add a dependency, and the folder Maven Dependencies should be created with your dependency in it.